# What should I do to broadcast Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, broadcast

I want to broadcast using Bluetooth module which is built into Raspberry Pi3.

- What should I do?
- Is there any document you can refer to?
- Do you have any Python source code for your reference?
- What settings should I set in Raspberry Pi 3 to broadcast?

Comment: What do you mean by Broadcast? BLE Advertising? GATT server? Turn discoverable mode for Classic Bluetooth?

Comment: yes BLE Advertising

Comment: I recomend to start with BLENO (https://github.com/noble/bleno). At least this is what we use in our development. Very simple and easy.